# RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir executes successfully but doesn't create directory

Tags: react-native, mkdir, rn-fetch-blob

I am trying to create directory in Downloads folder using RNFetcBlob. **It doesn't throw any error but folder doesn't get created....**

This is the method I am using...

```
async createAppDir() {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );

        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(GlobalVars.APPDIR)
                .then((res) =>
                    {
                        if (!res) {
                            console.log("Creating App directory...", GlobalVars.APPDIR)
                            RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(GlobalVars.APPDIR)
                                .then((res) => {console.log("App directory created..")})
                                .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
    }
```

I have added permissions in AndroidManifest.xml..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Console logs....

```
[Sat Jul 25 2020 10:16:30.966]  LOG      Creating App directory... /storage/emulated/0/Download/gifit/
[Sat Jul 25 2020 10:16:30.967]  LOG      App directory created..
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
async createAppDir() {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );

    const isGranted = granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === true;

    if (isGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        const assetsDirExists = await RNFetchBlob.fs.isDir(GlobalVars.APPDIR);
        if(!assetsDirExists) {
            RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(GlobalVars.APPDIR)
                            .then((res) => {console.log("App directory created..")})
                            .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code it doesn't even enter  if condition if (isGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {.....I had to change it to if (isGranted) { and run it.....this time it entered inside if condition but folder not created.....it printed "App directory created.." but when checked inside downloads folder i dont see the folder....

Answer (score 0):

I change the below versions in android/bundle.gradle file and it started working....

Changed below versions

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

To

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
```